# Error importing SSIS package with Konesans File system Watcher task into SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

I am importing SSIS packages to **SQL Server 2008** that were originally built for SQL Server 2005. I upgraded them in VS2008 and them imported them. They all import and work except for the one with the **Konesans File system Watcher task**. I installed in the setup exe for  Konesans File system Watcher SQL Server 2008 on my dev pc and the production server, but still get this error:

> Exception from HRESULT: 0xC0010026 (Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap)

Any advice?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Obvious question first...

Have you donwloaded the correct version.  In the link below halfway down the page you have the Downloads section for SQL 2005 and SQL 2008.

[File Watcher Task](http://www.sqlis.com/post/File-Watcher-Task.aspx)

Comment: Yes, I installed the SQL Server 2008 version of the File System Watcher task